# What happens if you superheat timber in a zero oxygen environment?

Tags: combustion, melting-point, mixtures

I was thinking to myself, what would happen if you were to put a lump of wood in a zero oxygen environment and superheat it? It couldn’t burn because fire needs fuel, heat and oxygen however because wood is a mixture of cellulose + other things, it can’t really just melt... If this were done, what would really happen?

Comment: [Pyrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrolysis)

Comment: A crude version of this process is done to create charcoal. Piles of wood are structured so that burning some creates a great deal of heat in the centre of the pile but little oxygen. The centre of the pile pyrolises leaving charcoal.

Comment: Also a name for methanol was *Wood spirit*. And ants were distilled leading to *formic* acid.

Comment: Similar: [Can paper burn without oxygen or air?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27465/can-paper-burn-without-oxygen-or-air)

Comment: @matt_black - indeed, and similarly turning coal into coke.